# This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created? I am very new to solidty . Any help highly appreciated

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract contracta{
    uint mapsize=10;
    struct request_task{ 
    uint task_id; 
    string ip_address;
    uint flag ;// submited, 1, excuteding, 2, finished, 3, failed
    uint task_submit_time; // 08:12:01 06/18/2018
    uint task_deadline; //  09:12:01 06/18/2018
    uint  provided_price; // maximum price: $10 per hour
    uint bandwidth; // minimum: 100.00 KBP
    }
    request_task[] private request;
    uint internal countera;
    function contracta() internal{
        add(1,"172.168.3.3",1,10,30,5,200);
        add(1,"172.168.3.3",1,10,30,5,200);

    }
    function add(uint _task_id,string _ip_address,uint _flag,uint _task_submit_time,uint _task_deadline,uint  _provided_price,uint _bandwidth) internal{
        request.push(request_task(_task_id,_ip_address,_flag, _task_submit_time,_task_deadline,_provided_price,_bandwidth));
    }
    function get()constant returns(uint){
        return request[1].task_submit_time;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't deploy a contract with an `internal` constructor. Use `public` instead:

```
function contracta() public {
    add(1,"172.168.3.3",1,10,30,5,200);
    add(1,"172.168.3.3",1,10,30,5,200);
}
```

BTW, you're using an extremely old version of the Solidity compiler. The current version is 0.4.23. There's an improved constructor syntax these days:

```
constructor() public {
    ...
}
```

Comment: A constructor **can** be `internal`, you just won't be able to deploy (or create) the contract. The point of a constructor being `internal` is if you want to explicitly state that you do not want to deploy (or create) the contract, yet you still want to inherit from it (i.e., extend it into a deployable contract).